# Highcharts threshold background color from 100 y-axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

This can be done using flotCharts, but I like using Highcharts a lot more for graphing data.

[image: Imgur]

It's done by using:

```
grid: {
    markings: [ { 
    xaxis: { from: -1, to: 12 }, 
    yaxis: { from: 100, to: 300 }, 
    color: "#FFA5A5" }]}
```

I was wondering if something like this is possible in highcharts ?

Right now I'm using limit-min and limit-max to draw a line at y-axis 10 like this: http://jsfiddle.net/kyUaR/32/ but I'd rather have the entire background change from that point upwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flots` markings is analagous to Highchart's [plot bands](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.plotBands).

Quick example:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    yAxis: {
        plotBands: [{
            color: '#FCFFC5',
            from: 100,
            to: 300
        }]
    },
    xAxis: { 
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']           

    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tK7ux/).